# Extracting an Id with GHC.Generics

Tags: haskell, generic-programming, ghc-generics

How to extract an identifier (in this case an integer) from a structure using `GHC.Generics`?

I have an `Id` type:

```
newtype Id = Id { _id :: Int }
```

and a lot of types that use that type:

```
data VarId = VarId Name Id SortId
data FuncId = FuncId Name Id [SortId] SortId
data SortId = Name Id
-- ... and 20 more of these things
```

On top of that there are other types that wrap the types above, for instance, identifiers:

```
data Identifier = IdVar VarId
                | IdFunc FuncId
                | IdSort SortId
                -- ... and 20 more of these things
```

Now I need to extract the `_id` field from any of these types containing an `Id` value. Currently we have tons of boilerplate for this, and I want to scrap it away using generics.

At first I thought about defining a class:

```
class Identifiable e where
    getId :: e -> Id

    default getId :: (Generic e, GIdentifiable (Rep e)) => e -> Id
    getId = gGetId . from

class GIdentifiable f where
    gGetId :: f e -> Id
```

in such a way that you'd have an `Identifiable` instance **only** if there is  one such `Id` type inside (in case that there are multiple of those like in `FuncId` above we return the first `Id` found when traversing the structure from top to bottom). Now the problem comes when I try to define the `GIdentifiable` instances for the product and sum. I would like to express something like:

```
instance (GIdentifiable a) => GIdentifiable (a :*: b) where
    gGetId (a :*: _) = gGetId a

instance {-# OVERLAPS #-} (GIdentifiable b) => GIdentifiable (a :*: b) where
gGetId (_ :*: b) = gGetId b
```

Which won't work because I'm defining duplicate instances.

I could redefine `Identifiable` so that `getId :: e -> Maybe Id` but this will remove some of the type safety, and introduce unnecessary checks when **I know** that a type contains at least one `Id`.

Is there a way to express this sort of case analysis when working with the type system?

Comment: You can use a closed type family to do the instance resolution. I would probably define a datatype representing the location of an `Id` in the structure and a type family producing values of that type. Then you can make instances of an auxiliary class follow that path.

Comment: Do you have any references that I can read? Should I just lookup "type families"?

Comment: I don't have time to help you find a good source right now, unfortunately. You may learn something from https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/14255#comment:5 but there are definitely better examples out there (including a few in questions I've answered here).

Comment: I think some sort of `Maybe`-like version is almost certainly necessary even to define a very certain version. Suppose you have `(x,y)`. This is certain to have an `Id` if and only if `x` or `y` is certain to have an `Id`. But if `y` is certain to have an `Id` and `x` *might* have an `Id`, then you want to check `x` first. There's going to be some kind of intertwined logic, I expect. Of course, this is only an issue if you have sum types around that can sometimes have an `Id` and sometimes not....

Comment: I'm trying using `type-families` but [I'm hitting the wall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47653880/using-type-families-and-generics-to-find-an-id-value) when I try to combine type-families with GHC.Generics :/

Comment: The wall I hit was really figuring out exactly what you wanted to do. Think particularly hard about what you want the constraint to be on `K1`.