# Using type families and Generics to find an Id value

Tags: haskell, type-families, ghc-generics

This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47453657/extracting-an-id-with-ghc-generics), where I wanted to avoid the boilerplate of extracting an `Id` value from a data structure, but in a type-safe manner.

I'll repeat the relevant details of the problem here: suppose you have a type `Id`:

```
newtype Id = Id { _id :: Int }
```

And you want to define a function `getId` that extracts this `Id` from any structure that contains at least one `Id` value:

```
class Identifiable e where
    getId :: e -> Id
```

Now the problem is how to define such a class in a **type-safe** manner, while at the same time **avoiding the boilerplate** using Generics.

In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47453657/extracting-an-id-with-ghc-generics?noredirect=1#comment82000025_47453657) I was pointed to type families, and in particular to the ideas [described in this blog post](http://mpickering.github.io/posts/2014-12-20-closed-type-family-data-types.html). As far as I understand the idea is to define a type-class `MkIdentifiable` such that:

```
class MakeIdentifiable (res :: Res) e where
    mkGetId :: Proxy res -> e -> Id
```

Where a value is of type `Res` only if there is at least one `Id` value that is nested inside of it:

```
data Crumbs = Here | L Crumbs | R Crumbs
data Res = Found Crumbs | NotFound
```

Then, it seems, one could define:

```
instance MakeIdentifiable (Found e) e => Identifiable e where
    getId = mkGetId (Proxy :: Proxy (Found e))
```

Now the question is how to define a type family for `Res` that is associated to the types of GHC.Generics (`U1`, `K1`, `:*:`, `:+:`).

I've tried the following:

```
type family HasId e :: Res where
    HasId Id = Found Here
    HasId ((l :+: r) p) = Choose (HasId (l p)) (HasId (r p))
```

Where `Choose` would be something like what is defined in the aforementioned blog post:

```
type family Choose e f :: Res where
    Choose (Found a) b = Found (L1 a)
    Choose a (Found b) = Found (R1 b)
    Choose a b = NotFound
```

But this won't compile as `HasId (l p)` has kind `Res` and a type is expected instead.

Comment: What is `Choose`?

Comment: I added a description of what `Choose` could be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty close to making `Choose` typecheck. `L1` and `R1` are constructors of `(:+:)`, not `Crumbs`. There's also a type `GHC.Generics.R :: *` which hides the `R` constructor from `Crumbs` at the type level, but you can use `'R` to disambiguate (singly-quoted names are constructors, doubly-quoted are type constructors).

It's also good practice to annotate kinds of types, much like we annotate types of toplevel functions.

```
type family Choose (e :: Res) (f :: Res) :: Res where
  Choose (Found a) b = Found ('L a)
  Choose a (Found b) = Found ('R b)
  Choose NotFound NotFound = NotFound  -- I'm not a fan of overlapping families
```